# Kotlin - Retrofit2 onResponse null Openweather

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making app with kotlin about weather using API Openweather. When i test my app onresponse  i get succesful but when  i try to get a data ("current")  the logcat  git me null.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    OpenWeatherClient.getWeather().enqueue(object : Callback<WeatherClass>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherClass>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Error")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<WeatherClass>, response: Response<WeatherClass>) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Exito") // With this i get a "Exito"
            Log.d("MainActivity", "${response.body()?.current?.pressure}") // With this i get null






class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    OpenWeatherClient.getWeather().enqueue(object : Callback<WeatherClass>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherClass>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Error")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<WeatherClass>, response: Response<WeatherClass>) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Exito") // With this i get a "Exito"
            Log.d("MainActivity", "${response.body()?.current?.pressure}") // With this i get null
```

Comment: could you please add a stack trace of the error?

Comment: 2020-08-06 21:21:51.393 23320-23320/com.example.colorweather D/MainActivity: null.

Comment: Hi Antonio, i dont know if this is that you meant, i am new in this, i  dont have other line of error

Comment: please open your LogCat (you can find the button in the bottom bar of android studio), then run your app and make sure you are checking the right device(double check the device is not disconnected) and the right process (check the package name). on the right most drop down select 'show only selected application'. then when you app crashes, you will see stack of red lines, copy all those lines and add in the question. also add your retrofit interface and OpenWeatherClient and your provided code snippet in incomplete, please provide the complete code too.

Comment: I follow your instructions and just i get this line in the logcat: 2020-08-09 22:34:31.998 30002-30002/com.example.colorweather D/MainActivity: Exito
2020-08-09 22:34:31.999 30002-30002/com.example.colorweather D/MainActivity: null. I share my code in git: https://github.com/VIAN258/Weather-1.git. Thanks a lot